# Android Gson не присваивает POJO объекту значение при использовании Retrofit2

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, gson

При использовании Retrofit2 столкнулся с проблемой. Создал POJO вида:

```
public class Root {
    private String str;
    private Map <Long, Long> map;
    //getters and setters
}
```

добавил класс MapJsonDesirializer
который отрабатывает, и даже правильно парсит JSON, но не присваивает его нужному полю.

```
public class MapJsonDeserializer implements JsonDeserializer<Map<Long, Long>> {
    @Override
    public Map<Long, Long> deserialize(
            JsonElement json,
            Type typeOfT,
            JsonDeserializationContext context
    ) throws JsonParseException {
        if (json != null) {
            Map<Long, Long> result = new HashMap<>();
            Iterator<Map.Entry<String, JsonElement>> iterator =
                    json.getAsJsonObject().entrySet().iterator();
            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                Map.Entry<String, JsonElement> next = iterator.next();
                result.put(Long.valueOf(next.getKey()), next.getValue().getAsLong());
            }
            return result;
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Подскажите пожалуйста, что могло пойти не так? Или может есть ещё какие нибудь способы распарсить HashMap, который приходит с сервера?

Comment: Gson как бы сам умеет парсить мапы без кастомных адаптеров. В вопросе мало информации чтобы что-то советовать. Покажите пример json-а, как подключаете `MapJsonDeserializer`. Сами попробуйте пройтись дебаггером, обложить всё логами.